# Query to show likes and dislikes, doesn't show all rows from first table

Tags: mysql

```
comment
id
comment
username
```

second rable

```
likesdislikes
id
likes
dislikes
comment_id
username
```

I have been trying to create a simple comment script that you can upvode the comment or dislike it. I have created the tables that i've shown.
Then I tried the following query:

```
select a.id a_id,a.comment,a.username,b.id,b.comment_id,b.username,b.likes,b.dislikes, sum(b.likes) as likescount, sum(b.dislikes) as dislikescount 
from comments a left join likesdislikes b on a.id=b.comment_id
GROUP BY b.comment_id 
ORDER BY likescount DESC, a.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

So the query is working, displays each comment with number of likes and dislikes it has, the issue is that i have 30+ comments, but this query only displays about 8, I guess the ones that both tables have in common?
Can anybody tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the group by to be on the comments table

```
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: When grouping on the left table in the join you do it for all the rows otherwise you only group on the ones that exists in the right table

Answer (score 0):

Your `LEFT JOIN` is correct but you are grouping by the column `comment_id` of the *right* table `likesdislikes` so your results do not include all the rows of the *left* table `comments`.
Also, when aggregating you should not include in the `SELECT` list columns that are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause or are not aggregated (although MySql allows it), so remove `b.id`, `b.username`, `b.likes` and `b.dislikes` because these would return values nondeterministicly chosen :

```
select 
  a.id a_id, a.comment, a.username, 
  sum(b.likes) as likescount, sum(b.dislikes) as dislikescount 
from comments a left join likesdislikes b 
on a.id = b.comment_id
GROUP BY a.id a_id, a.comment, a.username 
ORDER BY likescount DESC, a.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```